# php find a string contains a keyword and get the string between tags

Tags: php, string, preg-match, strpos, strstr

I had a string contains html tags, and I want to get the whole string between  which contains the keyword `"GB"`.

sometimes there are different class or style attributes in the `<td>`, and also there might have different capacity between tags, so I was thinking to find `"GB"` or `"gb"` and then get whole string between `">"` and `"<"`... but just have no idea how...

example of my string as shown as below:

```
$str='<tr>
    <td class="table_title13_bg_gray_line" width="171" align="left">Capacity</td>
    <td class="table_line_x_h10" width="647" align="left">&nbsp;16GB/32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
</tr>';
```

From the string above, I would like to get the string `"16GB/32GB/64GB/128GB"`
Can anyone please let me know what should I do?

EDIT:
And says if there are some tags in `"16GB/32GB/64GB/128GB"`,

ex.
`<td class="table_line_x_h10" width="647" align="left">&nbsp;16GB/<span style="color:red;">32GB</span>/64GB<br/>128GB</td>`

it seems the pattern `$pattern = "/<td ?.*>(.*?)<\/td>/";` wont't work, so what else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried and solved the question on my own...
answer here and hope it's useful for someone else.

```
$pattern = "/<td ?.*>(.*)<\/td>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
foreach( $matches[0] as $key=>$val){ 
    if(preg_match('/GB/i',$val)){
        echo $val;
    }
}
//output: 16GB/32GB/64GB/128GB
```

but still wondering is there any better or easier way?

#### EDITED:

ok i got it... i really hate regular expression...

```
$pattern = '/[<td ?.*>](.*?)<\/td>/s';
```

this can solve the case if the string between td tags containing other tags... just a simple []...

Comment: @mishan oh yes thank you, but I will wait till tomorrow to see if there's any other better answer =D

Answer (score 1):

How about using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$str='<td class="table_line_x_h10" width="647" align="left">&nbsp;16GB/<span style="color:red;">32GB</span>/64GB<br/>128GB</td>';
preg_match_all('/(\d+GB)/i', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16GB
            [1] => 32GB
            [2] => 64GB
            [3] => 128GB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16GB
            [1] => 32GB
            [2] => 64GB
            [3] => 128GB
        )

)
```

Comment: hmm.., this would be a good solution, but is there any other easier solution to get whole string in the case if today I want to search other keywords from the string but not GB? 
i did something like: 
`if(preg_match('/Capacity/i',$val)){
   $arr_index = array_search($key, array_keys($matches[0]));
   $arr_index += 1;
   echo $matches[0][$arr_index].'<br/><br/>';
  }`
it will return the whole string between the next td tags after "capacity", but return nothing if the string contains other tags

Comment: @GabbyChen: I'm not sure to understand what you mean :-( , but if your request is more complex than that, you should use an html parser.